# Microsoft Speech Platform

Tags: visual-studio, microsoft-speech-platform

I'm following the instructions in 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh361572(v=office.14).aspx but after installing the runtime, the voice, and the SDK, I couldn't figure out how to reference the `Microsoft.Speech.Synthesis` namespace on my Windows 7-64 bit machine with Visual Studio 2013 community edition update 4.

What's the real purpose of the SDK and how do I configure.

The installers are 64bit versions, and the voice synthesis works

PS: If you really think that my question is unappropriate here, please just put it in the comments or answers and suggest me where should I put it. I'll b glad move it far from your judgement in less than 10 hours

Comment: Hey @Pizzaboy I don't suppose you ever got a reply for this? I'm having kind of the same problem, except I cannot synthetize any audio, did you ever find out how to configure and use the SDK?

Comment: No still have to find out. Did you install the runtime and the voices along with the SDK?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I started using System.Speech instead, haven't had those problems yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to use `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Speech.dll` (for whichever .NET version is appropriate). It is a wrapper around `Microsoft.Speech.dll`. I was [having problems selecting the voice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34776593/speechsynthesizer-selectvoice-fails-with-no-matching-voice-is-installed-or-th), but it turned out to be just build configuration.

Comment: I guess it's right, I solved it by including the dll into the project as a reference. Pretty tricky thought