# SpeechSynthesizer.SelectVoice() Fails with "No matching voice is installed or the voice was disabled"

Tags: c#, text-to-speech, speechsynthesizer, microsoft-speech-platform

I am modifying [Scott Hanselman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6380/scott-hanselman)'s [BabySmash](https://github.com/shanselman/babysmash) code to support other languages.

1. I installed the speech platform and a new language per [these steps](https://superuser.com/questions/590779/how-to-install-more-voices-to-windows-speech).
2. The language now shows up in the registry:

   [image]
3. The language can now be selected and played by Windows:

   [image]
4. `System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer.GetInstalledVoices()` now returns the voice.
5. However `SelectVoice()` in the code below throws the error **"System.ArgumentException: Cannot set voice. No matching voice is installed or the voice was disabled."**

```cs
string phrase = null;
SpeechSynthesizer speech = new SpeechSynthesizer();
CultureInfo keyboardCulture = System.Windows.Forms.InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage.Culture;
InstalledVoice neededVoice = speech.GetInstalledVoices(keyboardCulture).FirstOrDefault();
if (neededVoice == null)
{
    phrase = "Unsupported Language";
}
else if (!neededVoice.Enabled)
{
    phrase = "Voice Disabled";
}
else
{
    speech.SelectVoice(neededVoice.VoiceInfo.Name);
}

speech.Speak(phrase);
```

6. I've tried upgrading to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Speech.dll`.
7. I've [verified that the versions](http://cvegso.squarespace.com/ucma/2013/3/1/cannot-set-voice-no-matching-voice-is-installed-or-the-voice-was-disabled) of `Microsoft.Speech.dll` and the language pack match.

   [image]
8. This code works for the default voices I've already had installed.
9. In desperation, I've even tried invoking `System.Speech.Internal.Synthesis.VoiceSynthesis.GetVoice()` directly through reflection, but same exact error.

I would greatly appreciate any help you can provide! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

ha ha I feel special: [this post on Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31167967/python-3-4-text-to-speech-with-sapi) actually solved my problem: build configuration platform needs to be **x64**, not `Any CPU`!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that some of the voices are not registered for all applications. There is a nice article about it here: https://www.ghacks.net/2018/08/11/unlock-all-windows-10-tts-voices-system-wide-to-get-more-of-them/

But for those who will find this answer when the above link doesn't work:

There are two registry keys which are involved.

1. Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\**Speech**\Voices\Tokens
2. Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\**Speech_OneCore**\Voices\Tokens

The first one is used when querying with *GetInstalledVoices()* API call.
The second one is used by the Windows Settings App.

To make the unlisted voices available for *GetInstalledVoices()* you need to copy the data of the desired voices from Speech_OneCore to the Speech node (and its x86 counterpart if needed).

- Step 1: Open the Windows Registry Editor (regedit.exe)
- Step 2: Open the list of available voices at Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech_OneCore\Voices\Tokens
- Step 3: Export the key of the voice you need
- Step 4: Modify the exported Registry file and
  replace

  - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\**Speech_OneCore**\Voices\Tokens\ with
  - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\**Speech**\Voices\Tokens\
- Step 5: Also add both entries for 32 bit apps (if you need them) by duplicating the entries and replace the

  - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\**Speech_OneCore**\Voices\Tokens\ with
  - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\**WOW6432Node**\Microsoft\**Speech**\Voices\Tokens\
- Step 6: Import the modified file to the registry.

Now it should work (a restart might be needed)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to install (x64) bits version of Microsoft Speech Platform SDK and  Microsoft Server Speech Platform Runtime. I think that you had installed (x86) bits of both and the plataform try to read it in (x64) bits.

I had the same problem that you but on the contrary and this works to me!

Answer (score 0):

In my case Instead of the library *System.Speech.Synthesis* i need to use *Microsoft.Speech.Synthesis*. For that we need to go to Solution Explorer on VisualStudio --> References and Browse for *Microsoft.Speech.dll*

```
using Microsoft.Speech.Synthesis;
```

After that you will have other Runtime Languages available.

```
        SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();    

        // Output information about all of the installed voices. 
        foreach (InstalledVoice voice in synth.GetInstalledVoices())
        {
            VoiceInfo info = voice.VoiceInfo;

            Console.WriteLine(" Name:          " + info.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(" Culture:       " + info.Culture);
            Console.WriteLine(" Age:           " + info.Age);
            Console.WriteLine(" Gender:        " + info.Gender);
            Console.WriteLine(" Description:   " + info.Description);
            Console.WriteLine(" ID:            " + info.Id);
        }
```

Comment: Microsoft.Speech looks deprecated. Assembly wouldnt load for me on Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

changing the user identity to Localsystem solve my problem !
[image]